# Any advantage to using Profile2 module vs. custom user account fields?

Tags: users

I'm trying to decide if I should bother messing with the Profile2 module. I need my users to have information like a real name stored and made available for other uses, but I'm not sure if there is an advantage to using the Profile2 module, or if I should just create custom user account fields for whatever I need.

Comment: Check the issues Queue for Profile2 (http://drupal.org/node/1413786).  There is a fatal error problem loading the module that has not been resolved as of 2/15/2012.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Profile2 module is only good if you need more then 1 type of profiles.
For example: 
         - a student profile, with certain fields.
         - a teacher profile, with different fields.

If you don't need different types, just stick with the custom user account fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had pretty much the exact same experience with creating custom profiles. I needed different profile types for different roles.

Comment: Great answer and comments. Just what I needed to know, thanks!

Comment: overwhelming answer buddy. Just what I needed to know, thanks a million - you deserve a monster congrats

Answer (score 3):

There are a few other things that you could take advantage of if profiles are nodes, for example, keep track of the number of page views to a profile. Or you could use node revisions.

Answer (score 1):

When needing private fields you can use http://drupal.org/project/profile2 too.

Or stick with custom user account fields and and http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions module which complicates configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add comment. So, adding in answer.
I am looking for the same functionality as #dimitril mentioned here.
I saw [Profile2 Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2). I am using Drupal-7 and profile2 is deprecated for Drupal 7. So, can I still use Profile2 module? or is there any other way?

I wanted to hide edit profile page for user role students, so that they can't change the password.

Appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Comment: Reread the docs for Profile2. It is the replacement for the core Profile which is what is deprecated. Profile2 is **not** deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Disagree that the only use case is if you need multiple profile types.

Use Profile2 if you want to allow other users to view a user's profile but not his account information. you can create a separate page for the public profile and keep sensitive information in the user fields.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be resource load. If you have a 100 fields and you load 20 users, that's a lot of data to get. If you split that in multiple profiles, you only need to load the profile that contains the relevant data.